# How does Rails know the primary key exists in this association according to my schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I'm a little confused:

From my understanding the table on the receiving end of the association (belongs_to) has the foreign key, and that is what connects that table to the table with the primary key.

In the following schema though, the primary is never specified (user_id) in the 'users' table. Only the foreign key(user_id) on the 'pics' table is.

So how does Rails know the primary key exists in the first place, if it's never even specified?

(I am using Devise)

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161220075312) do

  create_table "pics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "pics", ["user_id"], name: "index_pics_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
   end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: 
   "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

These are my models:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pics
end
```

Pic.rb

```
class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: The primary key in the `users` table is `id`, not `user_id`. You don't have to specify it, because [`create_table`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table) creates it automatically.

Comment: Alright, thank you for educating me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails automatically adds a primary key called id by default to all tables, so the table users has an 'id' primary key.

In the docs: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

> A primary key column called id will also be added implicitly, as
>   it's the default primary key for all Active Record models

Comment: I see, that's interesting. Thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 2):

To add to answers of Joel and Stefan, this is called "convention over configuration" and it is a core strength of rails.

So even though there aren't any foreign keys (the db objects) in your schema, rails sees `has_many :pics` and it **assumes** there must be a table called "pics" with a column named "user_id". And values of that column must correspond with values of column 'id' in table 'users'.

If you do things the rails way, you can write this configuration-free code. But if you, say, wrap a legacy database, where naming does not match rails' expectations, you can override the names.

```
has_many :pics, foreign_key: 'uid'
```

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer, Sergio. I understand this concept a lot better now!